# Where to append an SSL certificate? (Domainprovider or Hoster)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a domain hosted at Bluehost.
The domain's DNS shows to another Hoster: Hetzner.

When asking Bluehost they told me, that they can only give me an SSL certificate, when i host my site with them and purchase a dedicated IP.

My Question is: Who do i need to ask for installing an SSL certificate (Bluehost or Hetzner, where the DNS shows too) and what do they need to do? Where to buy it?

I have currently no clue how this all works :/

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be on topic here. You may wish to visit our sister site [webmasters.se] and check their FAQ and search for similar questions that have already been answered.

Comment: Cut the shilling middle-men out and just get an SSL certificate from a reputable place like GeoTrust. You'll need a dedicated IP address from your host, but that's all you need from them.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a dedicated IP address for your site, you can buy it from any SSL certificate seller. Just make sure that you are not on a shared hosting, with a shared IP address.